# How to set up a cpanel cron job for yii controller action on admin cms

Tags: content-management-system, yii, cron, command, cpanel

I've a web site, which is built on yii framework. I need to set up a cron job for a controller's action from the Cpanel cron job.
I've tried the below command and its working fine
GET http://www.mydomain.com/controller/action

Here is the my problem. I need to execute a controller's action which is inside the admincms. command should be as below,
GET http://www.mydomain.com/admincms/controller/action

But this is not running. I think this is because of password protection of the admin CMS.
(This cron is generating the sitemap for the site. This is related to the CMS. Thats why I need to use a controller inside the admin)

Any idea is appreciated???

Irawana

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are correct, the yii access rule for this controller should be changed.

Open the controller class and go to **accessRules** function and include the action for unauthenticated user like.

```
    array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
    'actions'=>array('action'), 
    'users'=>array('*'),
),
```

Comment: put any debug code in your action function and try from browser and see the debug code is accessed?

Comment: Thanks, It fixed the permission issue. But can you confirm the command "GET mydomain.com/admincms/controller/action";. I'm sure "GET mydomain.com/controller/action"; is working. Have you any idea, how to run a controller action on the admin cms

Comment: you URL mydomain.com/admincms/controller/action is correct only test from browser. This is working correctly from browser?

Comment: yes, its working from the browser. But the cron is not working.

Comment: I found the issue. Controller name is case sensitive on the cron command while action name is not case sensitive. Now its ok.